# Google map doesn't display when using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i tried to apply google map to my AngularJS project from this [Link](http://codepen.io/MarcMalignan/pen/jABfk)

and it works well without state (ui-router) but when i tried to put it into my project which has several states, map doesn't display but... it can search for a place and get longitude, latitude as you can see in the pic

[image]

Here's part of my code

Service: app.js

```
myApp.service('Map', function($q) {

    this.init = function() {
        var options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.00594130000002),
            zoom: 13,
            disableDefaultUI: true    
        }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("map"), options
        );
        this.places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
    }

    this.search = function(str) {
        var d = $q.defer();
        this.places.textSearch({query: str}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                d.resolve(results[0]);
            }
            else d.reject(status);
        });
        return d.promise;
    }

    this.addMarker = function(res) {
        if(this.marker) this.marker.setMap(null);
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            position: res.geometry.location,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        this.map.setCenter(res.geometry.location);
    }

});
```

Controller: app.js

```
myApp.controller('VenueController', function(Map,$rootScope, $scope, $auth, $state, $http) {

Map.init();

$scope.place = {};

$scope.search = function() {
    $scope.apiError = false;
    Map.search($scope.searchPlace)
    .then(
        function(res) { // success
            Map.addMarker(res);
            $scope.place.name = res.name;
            $scope.place.lat = res.geometry.location.lat();
            $scope.place.lng = res.geometry.location.lng();
        },
        function(status) { // error
            $scope.apiError = true;
            $scope.apiStatus = status;
        }
    );
}
});
```

HTML: venue.html

```
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
    <label> Location : </label>
    <form name="searchForm" novalidate ng-submit="search()">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input name="place" type="text" class="form-control" 
        ng-model="searchPlace" required autofocus />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" 
            ng-disabled="searchForm.$invalid">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="map"></div>

<form name="resForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate 
ng-submit="send()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="resName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input name="resName" type="text" class="form-control" 
            ng-model="place.name" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="resLat" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Latitude</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input name="resLat" type="number" class="form-control" 
            ng-model="place.lat" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="resLng" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Longitude</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input name="resLng" type="number" class="form-control" 
            ng-model="place.lng" required />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sorry if the code I show you is difficult to read

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide your code in plunkr??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `div` that contains map, or it's parent, or it's parent's parent (any DOM predecessor) has `display:none` style (what I presume happens when you change states: you hide some views and display other) the map view won't initialise properly. You have to trigger `resize` event on map when the visibility changes. (I think this is happening in your case, judging from the screenshot you provided, the API loaded sucesfuly, only the view is not properly initialised) Just add this code to the `Map` service:

```
this.resize = function() {
     if(this.map) google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');
}
```

**EDIT**

In your code, the map is inside the `div id="addVenue"`. So you need to trigger the resize right after the div is being displayed. To achieve this, add this function to your `VenueController`:

```
$scope.mapresize = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ Map.resize(); }, 10);
}
```

And call it in the `venue.html` view when you are about to display the `addVenue` div. Find a line with link to `href="#addVenue"` and change it like this:

```
<div class="sm-st clearfix"  href="#addVenue" ng-click="mapresize()" data-toggle="tab">
```

ALSO!! there is another problem with your application. In style.css REMOVE these 3 lines:

```
img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

They cause google maps to not function properly. Because google maps uses images internally and if you add this constrain they will break.

Comment: did you make sure that the div was visible at the moment you called resize? maybe put some timeout on it to be sure. Anyway, cannot help you further at this point, I would need a working code example or at least the main layout and how you handle states..

Comment: i tried it, still not work. but i tried to put it to the default page (no state change) and there is a red dot appear as you can see in this pic http://www.mx7.com/i/c79/9xBZbH.PNG